# How can I access the depth of a given sectioning command?

Tags: sectioning, expl3

In the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands), we can see a table that gives the depths of the sectioning commands:

part: -1
chapter: 0
section: 1
subsection: 2

etc.

Is there any way to access this information dynamically through either LaTeX2e or L3?  Maybe something like

```
\section_depth { section } :=> 1
```

---

#### EDIT

From what Marco said in the comments, this information may be useful:

```
$ texdef --tex latex @startsection

\@startsection:
macro:#1#2#3#4#5#6->\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi \par \@tempskipa #4\relax 
\@afterindenttrue \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@ \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse \fi 
\if@nobreak \everypar {}\else \addpenalty \@secpenalty \addvspace \@tempskipa \fi \@ifstar 
{\@ssect {#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg {\@sect {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}
```

Comment: It's a convention and the number which represents the depth of a sectioning command is the second mandatory argument of `\@startsection`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the standard classes, but also in `memoir` and KOMA-Script classes, the level for parts and chapters is not directly available. You can define a command `\getsectionlevel` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getsectionlevel}{m}
 {
  \sean_get_section_level:N #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sean_get_section_level:N #1
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
   {
    \str_case_x:nnn { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
     {
      { book } { \cs_gset:cpx { booklevel } { -1 } }
      { part } { \cs_gset:cpx { partlevel } { -1 } }
      { chapter } { \cs_gset:cpx { chapterlevel } { 0 } }
     }
     { \__sean_get_lower_level:No #1 { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \ddt % should be a proper error message
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sean_get_lower_level:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \__sean_get_lower_level:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sean_get_lower_level:Nw #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 \q_stop
 {
  \str_if_eq:nxTF { #4 } { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
   {% we're with memoir
    \cs_gset:cpx { \cs_to_str:N #1 level } { #5 }
   }
   {
    \cs_gset:cpx { \cs_to_str:N #1 level } { #4 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sean_get_lower_level:Nn { No }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\getsectionlevel{\chapter}

\show\chapterlevel

\getsectionlevel{\subsection}

\show\subsectionlevel
```

The macro `\getsectionlevel<command>` defines `\<command>level`.

We do a direct definition for the built-in commands; for lower levels we exploit the fact that they are defined by something like

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}...
```

so when we expand once `<command>` the third bit will be what we are looking for. For `memoir` one has to use a sligthly different path, because that class adds a hook `\@startsection` so the argument we need is shifted one place right.

Note that this will go crazy if a package such as `titlesec` is loaded. Probably it's much simpler to be confident in a normal setup:

- `book` -2 (only in `memoir`)
- `part` -1
- `chapter` 0
- `section` 1
- `subsection` 2
- `subsubsection` 3
- `paragraph` 4
- `subparagraph` 5

Answer (score 7):

If package `hyperref` is loaded, the numbers are encoded in macros `\toclevel@<section>` and `\sectiondepth` can be defined as (without error checking):

```
\newcommand*{\sectiondepth}[1]{\csname toclevel@#1\endcsname}
```

Otherwise the easiest way is probably to define such a command, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\secnum@book}{-2}% memoir
% test, if \chapter is defined without defining it
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname chapter\endcsname\relax
  \newcommand*{\secnum@part}{0}% article
\else
  \newcommand*{\secnum@part}{-1}%
  \newcommand*{\secnum@chapter}{0}%
\fi
\newcommand*{\secnum@section}{1}
\newcommand*{\secnum@subsection}{2}
\newcommand*{\secnum@subsubsection}{3}
\newcommand*{\secnum@paragraph}{4}
\newcommand*{\secnum@subparagraph}{5}
\newcommand*{\sectiondepth}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{secnum@#1}{%
    ??% error: section type is not known
  }{%
    \csname secnum@#1\endcsname
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The problem is that, in general, there's *no* way to know: classes might use whatever value for the levels they want.

Comment: @egreg: There is counter `secnumdepth`. A class that uses different values for the section commands for the standard classes would violate the interface of counter `secnumdepth`. Of course, a class/package could provide additional section levels (e.g. `book` of class `memoir`). Thus there is no way to be 100% sure. Also `\@startsection` does not help, a class can ignore it and use different macros for implementing the document division commands.